# Push message to AIR app from Java Server

Tags: java, actionscript-3, sockets, flex3

I am looking for solutions for a problem that we are facing. We are planning to make a POC for Desktop Alert application. We will have a desktop AIR app that will connect to a Java Server. The server will need to notify Desktop App when it has a notification which will be displayed on the screen.

A couple of options that we have discovered are :
1. Keep a persistent connection between the AIR app and the Server, using some sockets and listen to any changes.
2. Poll the Server at intervals to check if some new data has come.

Since these options don't seem optimal (persistent connection) or seems performance wise (polling) better.

Is there a better solution for this problem or do we have to choose one of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you could use a [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS) message service if you want to push messages to your client. Or a regular remote service with polling enabled.
It is built in out of the box and well tested equipment :)

Other technologies like [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org) or [WebOrb for java](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-java/overview.html) are also possibilities.

Cheers